# No module named 'tensorflow_examples' after installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

In my Notebook's first cell, I wrote :

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git
!pip install -U tfds-nightly
```

On the next cell :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow_examples.models.pix2pix import pix2pix
```

But it gives me : **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_examples'**

```
Notebook - version : 6.0.3
Tensorflow - version : 2.0.0
```

Do I need to install additional some modules ?

Here is the pip install log :

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git
  Cloning https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git to c:\users\mua\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-qtmqgj7m
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): tensorflow-examples===b30a40f9416fc38cfa91ca03d835ba1fc432a824- from git+https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git in e:\software\python 3.5\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py in e:\software\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-examples===b30a40f9416fc38cfa91ca03d835ba1fc432a824-) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in e:\software\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-examples===b30a40f9416fc38cfa91ca03d835ba1fc432a824-) (1.14.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: tensorflow-examples
  Building wheel for tensorflow-examples (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for tensorflow-examples (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for tensorflow-examples: filename=tensorflow_examples-b30a40f9416fc38cfa91ca03d835ba1fc432a824_-py3-none-any.whl size=136427 sha256=40d5b23f277f4634313116bf6205588e8668a499798fe1c7fdad143fc6144b68
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\MUA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-5wvvxv8d\wheels\e2\f1\08\a5d8eb62f62cc814d511a70115a5467b1135ec8270dd16d620
Successfully built tensorflow-examples
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git 'C:\Users\MUA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-qtmqgj7m'
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 20.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'e:\software\python 3.5\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting tfds-nightly
  Downloading tfds_nightly-3.2.1.dev202007220105-py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wrapt in e:\software\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from tfds-nightly) (1.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy in e:\software\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from tfds-nightly) (1.17.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: tqdm in e:\software\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from tfds-nightly) (4.45.0)
Collecting tensorflow-metadata
  Downloading tensorflow_metadata-0.23.0-py3-none-any.whl (43 kB)
Collecting promise
  Downloading promise-2.3.tar.gz (19 kB)
Collecting dill
  Downloading dill-0.3.2.zip (177 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six in e:\software\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from tfds-nightly) (1.14.0)
Collecting attrs>=18.1.0
  Downloading attrs-19.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: protobuf>=3.6.1 in e:\software\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from tfds-nightly) (3.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: absl-py in e:\software\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from tfds-nightly) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: termcolor in e:\software\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from tfds-nightly) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: requests>=2.19.0 in e:\software\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from tfds-nightly) (2.23.0)
Collecting future
  Downloading future-0.18.2.tar.gz (829 kB)
Collecting googleapis-common-protos
  Downloading googleapis_common_protos-1.52.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (100 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools in e:\software\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from protobuf>=3.6.1->tfds-nightly) (41.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in e:\software\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->tfds-nightly) (1.25.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna<3,>=2.5 in e:\software\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->tfds-nightly) (2.9)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: certifi>=2017.4.17 in e:\software\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->tfds-nightly) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in e:\software\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->tfds-nightly) (3.0.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: promise, dill, future
  Building wheel for promise (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for promise (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for promise: filename=promise-2.3-py3-none-any.whl size=21498 sha256=82af1fb81258e76c2ddec82ec8870ec0901b560e2547ddff0f81e096cd65fdc2
  Stored in directory: c:\users\mua\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\b6\3e\4e\d80f74df03a8059f631b23ec49939d8fa0a2633522596b6ffd
  Building wheel for dill (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for dill (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for dill: filename=dill-0.3.2-py3-none-any.whl size=78977 sha256=22a67eb861aca650bc9f1e039c15cb8ef9a87fbe88a139952868f352dd8f51aa
  Stored in directory: c:\users\mua\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\5c\4b\fd\db4143df7b4a4301b4068a2ed49f300b76b13d87b23bf375da
  Building wheel for future (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for future (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for future: filename=future-0.18.2-py3-none-any.whl size=491061 sha256=f19a6fd742fd80f4a1995a132c1c10b6de14b112ef5110bcb31eff13a2379306
  Stored in directory: c:\users\mua\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\c4\f0\ae\d4689c4532d1f111462ed6a884a7767d502e511ee65f0d8e1b
Successfully built promise dill future
Installing collected packages: googleapis-common-protos, tensorflow-metadata, promise, dill, attrs, future, tfds-nightly
Successfully installed attrs-19.3.0 dill-0.3.2 future-0.18.2 googleapis-common-protos-1.52.0 promise-2.3 tensorflow-metadata-0.23.0 tfds-nightly-3.2.1.dev202007220105
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 20.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'e:\software\python 3.5\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: What does `pip show -f tensorflow_examples` return?

Comment: everything installs correctly, I have already attached the log here.. @hoefling

Comment: Ok, I'll ask this the other way. Does the file `e:\software\python 3.5\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_examples\__init__.py` exist? Is `e:\software\python 3.5\lib\site-packages` in `sys.path`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42451#issuecomment-679884323):

```
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git
```

It worked for me.