# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_examples'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried running these three lines of code.

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow_examples.models.pix2pix import pix2pix
```

And it ended up in this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_examples'

I tried running the solution from [No module named 'tensorflow_examples' after installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63463856/no-module-named-tensorflow-examples-after-installing)

I am also running on a virtual environment.

Comment: `pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git`    ! this no is problem?

Comment: hi sry i am not really sure what you are asking

Comment: remove exclamation mark from pip install command @JohnBeats

Comment: hi it works thank you so much @I'mSRJ. May I ask why exclude the exclamation mark? Because I went to google they said the exclamation mark refers to executing command from the OS and when i ran with it, the code "!pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git" is also able to run

Comment: using !  before any command works with ipython.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what is suggested in the comments,

As per the latest documentation guidelines, pix2pix needs to be used in the following manner :

```
dataset_name = '<dataset_name>'

_URL = f'http://efrosgans.eecs.berkeley.edu/pix2pix/datasets/{dataset_name}.tar.gz'

path_to_zip = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    fname=f"{dataset_name}.tar.gz",
    origin=_URL,
    extract=True)

path_to_zip  = pathlib.Path(path_to_zip)

PATH = path_to_zip.parent/dataset_name
```

you can refer it online as well on the website [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/pix2pix)